# How to handle errors when localStorage permission is not granted?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I came across this interview question which asked me the question how do you handle errors when localStorage permission is denied.

I researched through docs and found that such an issue could arise if user has setup browser to deny use of storing data. This results in code throwing `SecurityError`

I tried to come up with a solution by wrapping `localStorage` methods viz. `setItem()` & `getItem()` into `try{..} catch(e){...}` blocks.

I was curious to know if a browser fails to give access to `localStorage` What other options do I have to store my data so that I can gracefully handle this scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function CheckStorageAllowance() {
  let storage;
  try {
    storage = window["localStorage"];
    let x = '__storage_test__';
    storage.setItem(x, x);
    storage.removeItem(x);
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return e instanceof window.DOMException && (e.code === 22 || e.code === 1014 || e.name === 'QuotaExceededError' || e.name === 'NS_ERROR_DOM_QUOTA_REACHED') && (storage && storage.length !== 0);
  }
}
let check = CheckStorageAllowance();
if (check) {
  // allowed
  console.log("Works");
} else {
  if (!check) {
    console.log("disabled");
    // Disabled
  } else {
    // quota exceeded 
    console.log(check);
  }
}
```

So essentially we check if we can set an item, remove it fast and return true, if not we determine what the exception was and as you may see there's few potential problems that can occur. Good luck.

Comment: Does `e.code = 22` & `e.code 1014` refer to `QuotaExceededError` & `NS_ERROR_DOM_QUOTA_REACHED`

Comment: It's a little confusing but it's performing a storage test and if anything goes wrong we check for Quota problems otherwise the return of error will be null and we know it just wasn't allowed at all. The window.DOMException will throw in all browsers but the code may differ or its error so that's why we check those.

Comment: I've modified the answer slightly to give more insight there; hope it works out for you. It should say disabled through stack overflow.